# Repair tile damage

Tags: tile

I would like to repair this damage.

It is in my shower.

It looks like some kind of paint/coating was sprayed over the tile.

What can I use to repair it?

[image]

Comment: is it something (extrusion) or a scratch/chip (indentation)? what type of tile is it?

Comment: @depperm It is an indentation. I am pretty sure it is ceramic tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like some kind of "Renew your shower with this spray on enamel!" type product over grayish tiles.  You can tell because the tiles and grout are all covered with the same white material.  It's flaking off in this area.

To repair you would need to find a similar enamel paint to touch up the bad area.  Finding a match might be hard, but an appliance enamel touch up spray might work.

Comment: I have seen that stuff but only when it is falling off, I agree matching it will be tough, might be better to clean paint that section so there is not a low point and repaint the whole thing that is what I have done on the cheep, replacing tile is the other option.+